# Nice representation of open sets in $\sigma$-algebras in certain circumstances

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. For a given topological base  $\mathcal{E}$ for $\tau$, let us denote Bor$(\mathcal{E})$, by the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{E}$.

Q.  Assume that Bor$(\mathcal{E})=$Bor$(\tau)$. Let $O$ be an open in $X$. Does there exists a sequence of 
open sets $\{O_n\}\subseteq \mathcal{E}$ with $O=\cup O_n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least under MA+$\neg$CH the answer is negative. It is known that under MA+$\neg$CH the real line contains an uncountable set A such that every subset of A is Borel in A (moreover, it is of type $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$).

Now consider the product $X=A\times\mathbb Q$ and let $\mu$ be the (metrizable separable) topology of the space X. Next, consider the topology $\tau$ on $X$, generated by the base $$\mathcal E=\mu\cup\{\{(x,0)\}:x\in A\}.$$

It is easy to see that the $\sigma$-algebra, generated by the base $\mathcal E$ coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, which coincides with the algebra of all subset of $X$. On the other hand, the open set $A\times\{0\}\in \tau$  cannot be represented as the countable union of basic set from the family  $\mathcal E$.